# Sharepoint 2013 search box press "Enter" refresh page and not trigger JS event

Tags: javascript

I am migrating a site from SP2010 to SP2013. One of JS is working on SP2010 mode and not in SP2013 evaluation page.

```
<input id="SearchBox" value="Search…" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){event.preventDefault();SearchKeyword('/pages/results.aspx','SearchBox',1);alert('triggered');}" onfocus="if(this.value == 'Search…') this.value = '';" onblur="if(this.value == '') this.value = 'Search…';" type="text" />
```

Expected behaviour (also the behaviour on SP2010 mode): user focus on the "searchbox" textbox, key in some value and press "Enter" on keyword, it will bring him to /pages/results.aspx?k=value .

Behaviour on SP2013 evaluation mode: after user press "Enter" entire page is refreshed and the querystring is not inserted.

How can I troubleshoot this case? The "onfocus" and "onblur" event are working. Also the "triggered" message is prompted when press enter.

I added "event.preventDefault" after some researching. However it does nothing on my function.

Comment: If the focus is not in Searchbox, press "Enter" will not refresh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by adding [ return false; ] at the end of JavaScript function. Like this:

onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13){SearchKeyword('/pages/results.aspx','SearchBox');***return false***;};"